# 12.10 Cinnamon problems

Tags: 12.10, cinnamon

I have just installed 12.10, but my graphic card doesn't support Unity (3D) and I installed Cinnamon.

My problem is that when I go to open Cinnamon it's like GNOME (when I go to GNOME there is the same, no changes). It's not like Cinnamon and when I try to put something in the desktop I can't.

My question is, how can I do for make Cinnamon run?

Comment: Please give me original (on your language) of "`it's like gnome (when I go to gnome there is the same, no changes). It's not like cinnamon and when I try to put something in the desktop I can't.`" That sentences don't have some sense. I fixed some of your bad grammar :)

Comment: @pablo.  You need to be more specific.  I use the same setup 12.10 with Cinnamon with no issues.  Its not clear what you are asking. What are you trying to put on you desktop?  Are you selecting the correct environment at log in?

Comment: ZDroid en mi lengua quiere decir que cuando entro a gnome sale exactamente lo mismo que en cinnamon

Comment: yes , i select cinnamon or cinnamon 2d and it open one enviroment like gnome (the same) and in the desktop there are no icons and i can´t add anything!

Comment: @pablo, your post should be in the form of a question, since that's what this site is set up for. Can you please rewrite you post so that you're asking something and not just listing off the problems you're having? Thanks.

Comment: Could you perhaps post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Use `dconf-editor`. Go to `org.gnome.desktop.background` and tick "Show desktop icons".

I have the same problem and I found the answer at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076524 .